# Identity Server4 access logged in users access token

Tags: access-token, identityserver4

I am using the Identity server 4 ( with .Net core 2.0 ) and all the clients are working perfectly and can retrieve the access_token. In my MVC client, i am using following command to retrieve the access_token.

```
var accessToken = await this.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

But for a functional requirement , I need to get this access_token inside my Identity server itself. The same code returns null when I'm trying to use it inside my Identity server's code.

It would be great if someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

May be your request authentication is not included the access token.

I guess it is rare case that Idm using access token.

You should be able to find out most of the information looking at the URL !! once you get the clientId then making a call to ConfigurationStore.

In general the following are the ways to get access_token

```
 var authenticateInfo = HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync("oauth2").Result;

        var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token"); 2.0
        string accessToken = authenticateInfo.Properties.Items[".Token.access_token"];
```